# Зачем нужна ссылка в конструкторе копирования?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Допустим имеем следующий класс

```
class String
{
 private:
    char* buf;
    int size;
 public:
    String(const char* str)
    {
       // code
    }

    String(const String& str)  // Почему здесь ссылка?
    {
        char* buf = new char[str.size + 1];
        memcpy(buf, str.buf, str.size + 1);
    }
}
```

Учитывая что аргумент  `String str` мы не собираемся менять, зачем передавать его по ссылке?

Comment: Там не обычная ссылка, а константная. Которая в том числе используется для исключения копирования объекта, но при этом не позволяет этот объект изменять.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы передать класс в функцию (или в конструктор) по значению (а не по ссылке), должен быть вызван какой-нибудь конструктор.

Если вы замените ссылку на `String str` и попробуете сделать `String a("x"); String b(a);`, то для `b` параметр конструктора `str` должен быть сконструирован. А каким конструктором он будет конструироваться? Тем же самым? Понятно, в чем проблема?

Поэтому язык запрещает создавать конструкторы вида `T(T)`.